# ml-gradle TDE 4.3.5

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have a problem to deploy TED in a specific database. I put them in the *schemas/tde* subdirectory of the database associated with my content database.

All is OK with the ml-gradle version 4.3.4, but when I update to use the 4.3.5 version, I have an error :

> Unable to load and validate TDE templates via tde.templateBatchInsert; cause: Local message: failed to apply resource at eval: Internal Server Error. Server Message: Server (not a REST instance?) did not respond with an expected REST Error message

I think it's because this new version uses templateBatchInsert.

The problem seems to appear only when I deploy on an AWS server.
Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a known issue with the `tde.templateBatchInsert` function in ML 10.0-9 - the underlying error is not available yet to a REST client, which includes ml-gradle. See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Loading-schemas#loading-tde-templates for more information.

In ml-gradle 4.3.6, the actual script used for TDE validation will be logged, which you can then paste into qconsole and run in order to see the root cause.

Alternatively, you can disable TDE validation by setting `mlTdeValidationEnabled=false` in gradle.properties.

Comment: Thank for answer, I will see what happen with the actual version of ml-gradle else I stay with 4.3.4 as long as possible

Answer (score 0):

I use the 4.3.4 version, because I'm unable to validate the TDE with 4.3.6 too